# PHP tcpdf shrink print multiple pages in one

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf, wkhtmltopdf, dompdf

I have been looking for a solution but can't find anything works right off the bat. The objective is to make a hand-out style page out of a multi-page PDF document.  Just like we can choose 6-up in most printer driver options.

Illustration:
[image]

The source is in PDF format, and I have calculated the page size that it should fit 6 pages on one.

Things I have tried so far: TCPDF, domPDF, wkhtmltopdf. None of them has the 6-up function.(or did I miss something in the document?)

The last option I have would be convert the source into PNG and use TCPDF::Image() to layout.  But I really don't want to do that, every conversion will introduce some artifacts into the document.

Comment: Just FYI, as you have seen this isn't possible with dompdf unless you design your original HTML that way. You could use one of the above libraries to generate your document then another tool (pdftk, FPDF/FPDI) to post-process.